# 6D file type in Paraview

Tags: paraview

I am looking for a way to reduce file size by using other formats that Paraview can display.
Right now I am using .csv file with 6D coordinates and one color attribute (integer as calculated by other program) that look like this:

```
...
x0,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,color(int)
...
```

This gives me **necessary** option to select which 2D/3D sections od 6D state space to display.

A problem is a large number of points and the .csv file is tens of GB in size.
Since all coordinates range from `0` to `n` (an arbitrary integer) I would like to store only attribute data. Coordinates could be specified e.g. as in .vtk structured point file

```
DIMENSIONS n n n n n n
SPACING 1 1 1 1 1 1
ORIGIN 0 0 0 0 0 0
POINT_DATA n^6
```

So the question is - Is there file type that can store only attribute data and allows to retain 2D/3D selection options as in .csv file?

P.S.
I can edit the output of a program that generates data (currently the .csv files).

Any other suggestion is welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not using native vtk format like .vtp or .vtu ?

Comment: If I understood well, those formats require to store (3D) coordinates of each point. I want only to store Lookup table. And my points have 6 coordinates + one (integer) property.
Right now, I have additional program that extract 3D cross-sections in .vtk (structured points), but I would like to load 6D data (also like structured points) in ParaView and then choose with filters what to display.

Comment: Still not sure to follow, there is native format for structured data as well, .vti, .vts, .vtr